# ElasticSearch synced with DB vs replicated DB for executing slow read queries

Tags: databases, performance

To minimize the impact on the performance of the production database, I'd like to execute heavy read queries and reporting-related queries against a replica of the database. These queries are executed from the application code.

Should I use ElasticSearch synchronized with the Postgres database (and use the ElasticSearch Query DSL), or replicate the Postgres database to another Postgres database (and simply use SQL)?

How would these solutions compare and which is the more widely accepted approach for the case of executing read-only slow queries from the application code?